# Error 102 when trying to use HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl

I trying to get my SSL certificate to work with apache2 on ubuntu.

Chrome gives me just the error:
Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED):

On this config:


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/swenet_info.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/swenet_info.key  

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
# MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: add a `netstat -tlupn` output.

Comment: also providing apache2ctl -S would tell us what apache configuration is

Answer (score 4):

Connection refused suggests that either Apache is not listening on port 443 or there is a firewall rejecting your connection on the apache host or somewhere in between.

If apache is not listening for connections (you can check it with netstat -ntpl | grep :443) you should add an appropriate [Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive to your configuration, such as

```
Listen 443
```